# Java: ArrayList to String?

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I try to print reverse of the entering number without any for loop. But I've got some issues with printing the Arraylist. How can I print the Arraylist [3, 5, 4, 1] as 3541 - without brackets, commas and spaces?

If not possible, how can I add my ArrayList elements to stringlist then print?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int yil, bolum = 0, kalan;
    Scanner klavye = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList liste = new ArrayList();
    //String listeStr = new String();
    System.out.println("Yıl Girin: "); // enter the 1453
    yil = klavye.nextInt();

    do{ // process makes 1453 separate then write in the arraylist like that [3, 5, 4,1]

        kalan = yil % 10;
        liste.add(kalan);
        bolum = yil / 10;
        yil = bolum;

    }while( bolum != 0 );

    System.out.println("Sayının Tersi: " + ....); //reverse of the 1453
    klavye.close();
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196628/printing-out-items-in-any-collection-in-reverse-order

Comment: You may want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196628/printing-out-items-in-any-collection-in-reverse-order?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    int yil, bolum = 0, kalan;
    ArrayList liste = new ArrayList();
    System.out.println("Yıl Girin: "); // enter the 1453
    yil = 1453;

    String s="";
    do { // process makes 1453 separate then write in the arraylist like that [3, 5, 4,1]

        kalan = yil % 10;
        liste.add(kalan);
        s= s + kalan;  // <------- THE SOLUTION AT HERE  -------

        bolum = yil / 10;
        yil = bolum;

    } while (bolum != 0);

    System.out.println("Sayının Tersi: " + s ); //reverse of the 1453

}
```

Comment: `StringBuilder` would be better here for appending characters but this seems to be most appropriate to solve the overall FIFO problem here so +1!

Answer (score 3):

- Read the entry as a String
- Reverse it with `String reverse = new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString();`
- Optional: parse it to an int if you need to do some calculations with that int.

Comment: [1,23] will become 321 insted of 231. I think tht ws the intented output.

Comment: My understanding is that the user enters one number (`1453` in the given example) and the goal is to reverse that number (to `3541` in the given example). I might have misunderstood.

Comment: but, wht is, if one of the numbers lrger than 9? I think that is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

**- Reverse** can be easily obtained using `Collections.reverse(List<?> l)`

**Eg:**

```
ArrayList<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();

Collections.reverse(aList);
```

**-** Use `For-Each` loop to print it out.

**Eg:**

```
for(String l : aList){

    System.out.print(l);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List strings = ...
List stringsRevers = Collections.reverse(strings);
// Have to reverse the input
// 1,23 -> 231 
// otherwise it would be 321   
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuiler();
for(String s: stringsRevers ){
    sb.ppend(s);
}
String out = sb.toString();
```